# How to Integrate Samsung Knox SDK with your Enterprise Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, samsung-knox

I am not able to figure out how to integrate Samsung Knox SDK with the android application to take control of Android devices through it. Knox Documentation is being too complex for me unable to figure out how to do it, can anyone please guide me through the same.

also, each and every sample application provided by Samsung Knox is throwing errors of static methods Not Found and app crashes.

being such a small community of Samsung Knox, unable to find solutions or tutorials

Error From Every Sample Applications provided on Samsung Knox Site:-

2022-06-30 12:24:30.920 10676-10676/com.samsung.knox.example.gettingstarted E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.samsung.knox.example.gettingstarted, PID: 10676 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getAPILevel()I in class Lcom/samsung/android/knox/EnterpriseDeviceManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.samsung.android.knox.EnterpriseDeviceManager' appears in /system/framework/knoxsdk.jar) at com.samsung.knox.example.gettingstarted.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:111) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2872) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6543) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)

Answer (score 0):

As a first step just make sure that your device admin is working fine without any Knox API.
Refer standard Android method for developing Device Admin
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin#developing

Once the admin app works fine, add flow for Knox License activation and then you must be able to use Knox API's. Make sure to add knoxsdk.jar file in the build path so that there are no build errors. Ref :
https://docs.samsungknox.com/dev/knox-sdk/sample-apps/get-started-knox-sdk-isv.htm